# Express Checkout Documentation Does Not Cover Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am working on a new PayPal implementation that needs to support recurring payments (billing plans and agreements). In the developer documentation, I see an article for "[Handling Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/)". At the top of this article is  a message that reads "Important: This integration method is Deprecated as of January 1, 2017. For new integrations, see the "[PayPal Express Checkout Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/)". However, there is absolutely ZERO discussion or coverage in the Express Checkout Integration Guide on how to initiate a recurring payment (set up a billing plan or agreement), the guide only covers how to initiate a one-time sale.

Is it possible to either update this documentation appropriately or provide some more details on how to initiate other types of payments via Express Checkout besides one-time sales?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The documentation on this is very frustrating! I dont suppose you managed to find an answer in the end?

Comment: I wish I had better news for you, I did not. I ended up going with the "deprecated" NVP/SOAP integration. The more I read the more I came to understand that, despite it being "deprecated", it is more mature and has functionality that is still being fleshed out / added to the REST version. I'll probably tackle it again later this year. The only drawback is that it renders the old-style PayPal login if I'm doing a recurring payment, but my users can live with that for now.

Comment: Thanks for this! When you say old style paypal login do you mean that it navigates away from the page and to paypal essentially? My client does not want this :/

Comment: Yes.

For one-time purchases, I was able to invoke the newer login which overlays my client's web page with a lightbox window.

For recurring payments, I had to invoke the old-style full page redirect which is definitely less seamless.

Message me directly if you want to swap code / get into the details.

Comment: So I only just saw your reply...I know this may be a bit irrelevant to you now but I ended up doing this: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Recurring-Payments-Billing/Custom-Recurring-amounts/td-p/1184190 Its way easier than implementing NVP/SOAP and sounds like it basically does the same thing. Lets hope this is useful to someone in the future!